# Append error message to input in jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

As the title implies I would like to append the jQuery Validation error messages to the input field or atleast have someone helping me with the positioning of them.

The error messages are messing up the form because they are more or less just popping up randomly.

I would like to display the messages under each of the input fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#register-form').validate({
    errorClass: 'error',
    rules: { //set rules for specific inputs
      name: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
      },
      email: { //refers to the inputs name
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      subject: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true,
      },
      workground: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true,
      },
      text: {
        required: true,

      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form action="php/PHPMailer/send-mail.php" method="post" id="register-form">
  <input class="contact-input-type1" name="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off">
  <input class="contact-input-type1" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse" autocomplete="off">
  <input class="contact-input-type2" name="subject" placeholder="Anliegen" autocomplete="off">
  <input class="contact-input-type2" name="workground" placeholder="Metier" autocomplete="off">
  <textarea maxlength="300" class="contact-textarea" name="text" placeholder="Nachricht" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="contact-submit" value="Abschicken">
</form>
```

Comment: They are not showing up randomly. Have you tried looking at the placement of the elements in the browser? They always follow the field they are validating. After validation errors show up right-click the elements and inspect them in the browser. Now you know what they look like and what classes they use .i.e: `class="error"` and now you can write CSS to target them and make them look pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Please see snippet below:

```js
$('#register-form').validate({
  errorClass: 'error',
  rules: { //set rules for specific inputs
    name: {
      required: true,
      lettersonly: true
    },
    email: { //refers to the inputs name
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    subject: {
      required: true,
      lettersonly: true,
    },
    workground: {
      required: true,
      lettersonly: true,
    },
    text: {
      required: true,

    }

  }
});
```

```css
label.error {
  float: none;
  color: red;
  padding-left: .5em;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form action="php/PHPMailer/send-mail.php" method="post" id="register-form">
  <input class="contact-input-type1" name="name" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off">
  <input class="contact-input-type1" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse" autocomplete="off">
  <input class="contact-input-type2" name="subject" placeholder="Anliegen" autocomplete="off">
  <input class="contact-input-type2" name="workground" placeholder="Metier" autocomplete="off">
  <textarea maxlength="300" class="contact-textarea" name="text" placeholder="Nachricht" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="contact-submit" value="Abschicken">
</form>
```